# Radio buttons, changing the background color PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, radio-button

Alright guys, so basically I have a form. By the time the user clicks submit, this form should output the users selections, or text, but also the background color of what the user selected.

Currently what is working is the text...and checkboxes. I cannot get the drop down selection to output... and when it comes to the background color.... I have no clue on where to start.. Kinda lengthy... sorry about that, just need some direction. An example of what it's supposed to look on output is here: http://omega.uta.edu/~cyjang/ctec4309/labex/php2/post_form_3a.php
Once you fill it out, you will see..

here is my HTML :

```
<hr size="1">

<h3>Form</h3>
* required fields
 <form action= "post3.php" method="post">
    Author * : <input type="text" name="author"><br/>
    Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
    Title * : <input type="text" name="title"><br/>

Tag: 
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="General Interests"> General Interests
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="Local Schools"> Local Schools
<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="Safety"> Safety
<br/>

 City *:
<select name="mycity">
<option value="Arlington" name"city">Arlington</option>
<option value="Dallas" name"city">Dallas</option>
<option value="FTW" name"city">Fort Worth</option>
</select> 
<br/>

 Background color *:
<input type="radio" name="bgcolor" value"yellow">  Yellow 
<input type="radio" name="bgcolor" value"blue">  Blue  
<br/>




Comment * : <br/><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>
<input type="Submit" name="SubmitThis" value="Preview">


  </form>
```

and HERE is my PHP:

```
//==========================
// Data validation
//==========================

// check to see if there is a form submission or not
if (array_key_exists("SubmitThis", $_POST)) {

// data validation
//  - check required fields

//== Modify the required and expected arrays below to fit your form ========
$required = array('title', 'author','comment','bgcolor', 'city');
$expected = array('title', 'author','comment','tag', 'email', 'city');
$missing = array();

// use foreach loop to run through each item in the expected array
foreach($expected as $thisField) {
    // setup a variable to store user input for this field name
    $thisUserInput = $_POST[$thisField];

    // check if this field is a required field
    if (in_array($thisField, $required)) {
        // check if user input of this field is empty, if yes, add this field to the missing array
        if (empty($thisUserInput)) {
            array_push($missing, $thisField);
        } else {

            ${$thisField} = $thisUserInput;
        }
    } else {
        ${$thisField} = $thisUserInput;
    }
}


    // after running through all expected fields, check the $missing array. if there is no required field missing, the $missing array will be empty.
    if (empty($missing)){
    // empty($missing) is true --> no missing field, proceed with business processes (in this example, display all user input.)

    // deal with array input, ex. $tag
    $tagStr = implode(", ", $tag);

    // print_r ($tag); // enable this line will print the $tag array, so you can see what's been stored in the $tag array.  It may help you to debug.

    // process author name and email
    if (!empty($email)) {
        $author = "<a href='mailto:$email'>$author</a>";
    }

    $output = "<p> <table border=2 cellpadding=5>
            <tr><th> Author:</th><td> $author </td></tr>
            <tr><th> Title:</th><td> $title </td></tr>
            <tr><th> Tag:</th><td> $tagStr </td></tr>
            <tr><th> City:</th><td> $city </td></tr>
            <tr><th> Comment:</th><td> <br>$comment </td></tr>
            </table></p>";

    } else {
    // empty($missing) is false --> $missing array is not empty -- prepare a message for the user

    $missingFieldList = implode(", ",$missing);
    $output = "The following fields are missing from your post, please go back and fill them in.  Thank you. <br>
                    <b>Missing fields: $missingFieldList </b>
                ";

}


} else {
$output = "Please post your message use <a href='post_form_3.php'>this form</a>.";
}



?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the drop down the `<option>` can only have a `value=""` attribute, not `name=""`. The name can only be in the `<select>` portion:

```
<select name="city">
    <option value="Arlington">Arlington</option>
    <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
    <option value="FTW">Fort Worth</option>
</select>
```

For the color, just use a simple style sheet (`css`):

```
$output = "
    <style>
        th,td { background-color: $bgcolor; }
    </style>";
```

Or, if you create a css class called "yellow" and "blue", you can assign the class:

```
 $output .= "
    <table border=2 cellpadding=5 class=\"$bgcolor\">
        <tr><th> Author:</th><td> $author </td></tr>
        <tr><th> Title:</th><td> $title </td></tr>
        <tr><th> Tag:</th><td> $tagStr </td></tr>
        <tr><th> City:</th><td> $city </td></tr>
        <tr><th> Comment:</th><td> <br>$comment </td></tr>
    </table>";
```

CSS file:

```
table.yellow td,
table.yellow th { background-color: #FFFF00; }

table.blue td,
table.blue th { background-color: #0000FF; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the drop down menu displaying an output. Still not getting the background color though. Rather than using an external css, I can just use <style></style> in the <header> area right? hmmmmm still not getting any color though. Wait, do I need to define the $bgcolor?

Comment: When they user selects yellow on the form, how do I make it output a yellow background color? and if the client selects blue on the form how do I output a blue background?

Comment: Yes You do need to define $bgcolor from your $_POST then it should work

Comment: welp lol i'm not getting anywhere. let's see so... thus far I have what you posted up top, and added in $bgcolor=$_POST['bgcolor']; no clue what to do after that? I know I need to do something with the HTML form code... just not sure what I put.

Comment: Give me about an hour or so if you can, I am not in front of a computer to give more assistance

Comment: Yeah definitely... much fun, much frustrating. Take your time.

Comment: Can you update your code in your question on the php page with what you are currently using?

Comment: nvm man I got it! lol i had no = next to my values for the color selection and bgcolor was not in the required field.

Comment: Oh yeah, jeez!! I see that now, I didn't even notice that....well there you go! Cheers.